# Extract a number from a paragraph using a pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract a number from a specific patter.

here is an example of the string "stable patients, including 3787 with".

That number can be anywhere after the word patients or before the word patients. I want to extract only the first set of numbers before or after a specific word.

Trying to use this, but not working

```
function get_numerics ($str) {
    preg_match('/Patients\s*(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: `\s*` is white space you want to just pull the first number after patients regardless of what is between? Also `Patients` is lower case in your example string you need the `i` modifier for regex to allow for that. `$matches[0]` will be the match, `$matches[1]` would be the integer.

Comment: Have you considered, that you may have to explain or define a relation between the number and the word patient(s)? What if the text contained a year, patients and a number of patients?

Comment: Can the number be anywhere in the string, or must it be directly beside the word "patients"?

Comment: There are tools online for live regex testing. Check this: http://regexr.com/3et6l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two regexp, one to find a number before your keyword, another to find the number after the keyword. If either is found, calculate the distance, in number of characters, between your keyword and the number. Then return the number that is closest to your keyword, per the calculated distances. You also probably want to limit the maximum distance possible between your keyword and the numbers; wouldn't make much sense to return a number that is a few hundreds characters from your keyword, right? I used 20 max characters below.

```
function get_numerics($str) {
    $word = 'patients';
    preg_match('/(\d+)[^\d]{1,20}?'.$word.'/i', $str, $matches_before);
    preg_match('/'.$word.'[^\d]{1,20}?(\d+)/i', $str, $matches_after);
    $distance_before = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $distance_after = PHP_INT_MAX;
    if (count($matches_before) == 2) {
        $distance_before = strlen($matches_before[0]) - strlen($matches_before[1]) - strlen($word);
    }
    if (count($matches_after) == 2) {
        $distance_after = strlen($matches_after[0]) - strlen($matches_after[1]) - strlen($word);
    }
    if (count($matches_before) == 2 || count($matches_after) == 2) {
        if ($distance_before < $distance_after) {
            return (int) $matches_before[1];
        } else {
            return (int) $matches_after[1];
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

var_dump(get_numerics("24 stable patients, including some"));
// Returns 24
var_dump(get_numerics("stable patients, including 3787 with"));
// Returns 3787
var_dump(get_numerics("24 stable patients, including 3787 with"));
// Returns 24, because it's the closest from the 'patients' keyword
var_dump(get_numerics("24 stable blablabla patients, including 3787 with"));
// Returns 3787, because it's the closest from the 'patients' keyword
var_dump(get_numerics("stable blablabla patients, including some that are not ok. But 3787 planes "));
// Returns FALSE, because 3787 is too far from the 'patients' keyword
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have something like this " Among 2933 patients, 1948", the system reads the 1948 as the patients.